# Fold / Recursion over Multiway Tree in f#

Tags: f#, tree, traversal, fold, multiway-tree

I am trying to adapt Brian's Fold for Binary Trees (http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/) to apply for Multiway trees.

Summarizing from Brian's Blog:

*Data structure:*

```
type Tree<'a> =  
    | Node of (*data*)'a * (*left*)Tree<'a> * (*right*)Tree<'a>  
    | Leaf 

let tree7 = Node(4, Node(2, Node(1, Leaf, Leaf), Node(3, Leaf, Leaf)),  
                    Node(6, Node(5, Leaf, Leaf), Node(7, Leaf, Leaf)))
```

*Binary Tree Fold function*

```
let FoldTree nodeF leafV tree =   
    let rec Loop t cont =   
        match t with   
        | Node(x,left,right) -> Loop left  (fun lacc ->    
                                Loop right (fun racc ->   
                                cont (nodeF x lacc racc)))   
        | Leaf -> cont leafV   
    Loop tree (fun x -> x)
```

*examples*

```
let SumNodes = FoldTree (fun x l r -> x + l + r) 0 tree7
let Tree6to0 = FoldTree (fun x l r -> Node((if x=6 then 0 else x), l, r)) Leaf tree7
```

**Multiway Tree version** *[not (fully) working]*:

*Data Structure*

```
type MultiTree = | MNode of int * list<MultiTree>

let Mtree7 = MNode(4, [MNode(2, [MNode(1,[]); MNode(3, [])]);  
                    MNode(6, [MNode(5, []); MNode(7, [])])])
```

*Fold function*

```
let MFoldTree nodeF leafV tree = 
    let rec Loop  tree cont =   
        match tree with   
        | MNode(x,sub)::tail -> Loop (sub@tail) (fun acc -> cont(nodeF x acc))
        | [] -> cont leafV
    Loop  [tree] (fun x -> x)
```

*Example 1*
Returns 28 - seems to work

```
let MSumNodes = MFoldTree (fun x acc -> x + acc) 0 Mtree7
```

*Example 2*

Doesn't Run

```
let MTree6to0 = MFoldTree (fun x acc -> MNode((if x=6 then 0 else x), [acc])) Mtree7
```

Initially I thought the `MFoldTree` needed a `map.something` somewhere but I got it to work with the `@` operator instead.

Any help on the second example and or correcting what I've done in the `MFoldTree` function would be great!

Cheers

dusiod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution could be

```
let rec mfold f a (MNode(x,s)) = f (List.fold (fun a t -> mfold f a t) a s) x
```

really, we can treat tree as a lineal struct (to fold it).

Use case

```
> mfold (+) 0 Mtree7;;
val it : int = 28
```

Filter is the same with normal fold (because `mfold` is a normal fold):

```
> mfold (fun a x -> if x = 6 then a else x + a) 0 Mtree7;;
val it : int = 22
```

That function could be generic (as `List.fold`, `Array.fold`, ... could be generics).

*"but the intention of the second is to return the whole tree modified so that any nodes which had the value 6 for example now have value 0"*

But that is not a `fold` computation, is a `map`!

You can do easilly (treating, again, as a lineal struct)

```
let rec mmap f (MNode(x,s)) = MNode(f x, List.map (mmap f) s)
```

Use case

```
> mmap (fun x -> if x=6 then 0 else x) Mtree7;;
val it : MultiTree =
  MNode
    (4,
     [MNode (2,[MNode (1,[]); MNode (3,[])]);
      MNode (0,[MNode (5,[]); MNode (7,[])])])
```

Again, I suggest to do it for each possible list container (`Seq`, `List`, `Array`, ...), it enable to user select best strategy in context.

Notes:

- I'm new in F#, excuse me if some is wrong.
- stack size should not be a problem, stack level is equal to tree's deep.

Comment: Hi josejuan, that solution works for the first case, but the intention of the second is to return the whole tree modified so that any nodes which had the value 6 for example now have value 0.  
  
Another alternative to Example 1 is:  
  
`let MFoldTree2 tree =   
    let rec Loop trees  =     
        match trees with     
        | MNode(x,sub)::tail -> x + (Loop sub) + (Loop tail)  
        | [] ->  0  
    Loop  tree`

Comment: @dusiod that is not a `fold`! is a `map`! :D (I have updated solution)

Answer (score 10):

The trick is that you need to pass one additional function to fold.

In Brian's version, the fold function just takes `nodeF` that is called with the value in the node and the two values produced from the left and right sub-trees.

That is not sufficient for multiway trees. Here, we need a function `nodeF` that is called with the value in the node and the result produced by aggregating all values of the sub-trees. But you also need a function - say `combineF` that combines value produced from multiple sub-trees of a node.

Your fold function is a good start - you just need to add one more recursive call to process `tail`:

```
let MFoldTree nodeF combineF leafV tree = 
    let rec Loop trees cont =   
        match trees with   
        | MNode(x,sub)::tail -> 
            // First, process the sub-trees of the current node and get 
            // a single value called 'accSub' representing (aggregated)
            // folding of the sub-trees.
            Loop sub (fun accSub -> 
              // Now we can call 'nodeF' on the current value & folded sub-tree
              let resNode = nodeF x accSub
              // But now we also need to fold all remaining trees that were
              // passed to us in the parameter 'trees'..
              Loop tail (fun accTail ->
                // This produces a value 'accTail' and now we need to combine the
                // result from the tail with the one for the first node 
                // (which is where we need 'combineF')
                cont(combineF resNode accTail) ))
        | [] -> cont leafV
    Loop  [tree] (fun x -> x)
```

Summing is easy, because we just use the `+` operator for both functions:

```
let MSumNodes = MFoldTree (+) (+) 0 Mtree7
```

Filtering the tree is more tricky. The `nodeF` function will get the element in the node and a *list* of child nodes (that is the result of aggregation) and produces a *single* node. The `combineF` function will get the result from a first node (that is a `MultiTree` value) and a list of children produced from the remaining nodes. The initial value produced from an empty tree is an empty list:

```
let MTree6to0 = 
  MFoldTree (fun x children -> MNode((if x=6 then 0 else x), children)) 
            (fun head tail -> head::tail) [] Mtree7
```

Comment: Amazing -  You are a F# Legend!! =P Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW: It is probably much easier to understand the problem when you first try writing the function without continuations. Continuations help you avoid stack overflow, but that is not that often a problem for reasonably sized trees. Once you have non-continuation version, it is not too hard to turn it into continuation-based one.

Comment: Tried that & don't even want to admit how much time i spent trying to get it that way...  now brain hurts too much to step through & properly understand your solution but it will get some proper attention v.soon. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TomasPetricek that whole CPS wrinkle in Brian's code sure makes it a bit trickier to master. But once you do master it, it is a very useful technique to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Could someone add the type signature to this?