# Decode JSON Multiway Tree into an F# Multiway Tree Discriminated Union

Tags: json, f#, tree, multiway-tree

I have the following JSON data in a documentdb and I would like to parse this into an F# multiway tree discriminated union

```
"commentTree": {
    "commentModel": {
        "commentId": "",
        "userId": "",
        "message": ""
      },
      "forest": []
    }
```

F# multiway discriminated union

```
type public CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel = 
| CommentDatabaseModelNode of CommentDatabaseModel * list<CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel>
```

where CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel is defined as

```
type public CommentDatabaseModel =
{ commentId : string
  userId : string
  message : string
}
```

I am referencing [Fold / Recursion over Multiway Tree in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875835/fold-recursion-over-multiway-tree-in-f) extensively.  I am not sure where to begin to parse such a JSON structure into an F# multiway tree.  Any suggestions will be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I guess the real question you want to ask is how to parse a recursive json structure into a corresponding recursive data type in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about this is by looking at what data you need in order to construct a `CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel`. It needs a `CommentDatabaseModel` and a list of `CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel`. So we need to write the following two functions:

```
let parseComment (input : JSON) : CommentDatabaseModel =
    ...

let parseTree (input : JSON) : CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel =
    ...
```

But wait, the `parseTree` function is the one we're trying to write right now! So instead of writing a new function, we just mark our current function with the `rec` keyword and have it call itself where needed.

Below is a rough example of how it could be done. The key thing to look at is `parseTree` which builds up the data by recursively calling itself. I've represented the JSON input data with a simple DU. A library like [Chiron](https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-13-chiron-json-ducks-monads/index.html) can produce something like this.

Note that this code parses all of the JSON in one go. Also, it's not tail-recursive, so you'll have to be careful with how deep your tree structure is.

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type JSON =
    | String of string
    | Object of (string * JSON) list
    | Array of JSON list

type public CommentDatabaseModel = {
    commentId : string
    userId : string
    message : string
}

type public CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel = 
    | CommentDatabaseModelNode of CommentDatabaseModel * list<CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel>


let parseComment = function
    | JSON.Object [ "commentId", JSON.String commentId; "userId", JSON.String userId; "message", JSON.String message ] ->
        {
            commentId = commentId
            userId = userId
            message = message
        }
    | _ -> failwith "Bad data"

let rec parseTree (input : JSON) : CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel =
    match input with
    | JSON.Object [ "commentModel", commentModel; "forest", JSON.Array forest ] ->
        CommentDatabaseModelNode (parseComment commentModel, List.map parseTree forest)
    | _ -> failwith "Bad data"

let parse (input : JSON) : CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel =
    match input with
    | JSON.Object [ "commentTree", commentTree ] ->
        parseTree commentTree
    | _ -> failwith "Bad data"


let comment text =    
    JSON.Object [
        "commentId", JSON.String ""
        "userId", JSON.String ""
        "message", JSON.String text
    ]

let sampleData =
    JSON.Object [
        "commentTree", JSON.Object [
            "commentModel", comment "one"
            "forest", JSON.Array [
                JSON.Object [
                    "commentModel", comment "two"
                    "forest", JSON.Array []
                ]

                JSON.Object [
                    "commentModel", comment "three"
                    "forest", JSON.Array []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

parse sampleData

(*
val it : CommentMultiTreeDatabaseModel =
  CommentDatabaseModelNode
    ({commentId = "";
      userId = "";
      message = "one";},
     [CommentDatabaseModelNode ({commentId = "";
                                 userId = "";
                                 message = "two";},[]);
      CommentDatabaseModelNode ({commentId = "";
                                 userId = "";
                                 message = "three";},[])])
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have temporarily postponed implementing this functionality in my app but I will get back to it.  Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've just implemented it along with using Chiron