# Simplify multiway tree traversal with continuation passing style

Tags: functional-programming, f#, continuation-passing

I am fascinated by [the approach used in this blog post](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/advanced-recursion-techniques-in-f/) to traverse a rose tree a.k.a multiway tree a.k.a n-ary tree using CPS.

Here is my code, with type annotations removed and names changed, which I did while trying to understand the technique:

```
type 'a Tree = Node of 'a * 'a Tree list | Leaf of 'a

let rec reduce recCalls cont =
    match recCalls with
    | [] -> [] |> cont 
    | findMaxCall :: pendingCalls ->
        findMaxCall (fun maxAtNode ->
                    reduce pendingCalls (fun maxVals -> maxAtNode :: maxVals |> cont))
        
let findMaxOf (roseTree : int Tree) =
    let rec findMax tr cont =
        match tr with
        | Leaf i -> i |> cont
        | Node (i, chld) ->
            let recCalls = chld |> List.map findMax 
            reduce recCalls (fun maxVals -> List.max (i :: maxVals) |> cont)
    findMax roseTree id 
    
// test it
let FindMaxOfRoseTree =
    let t = Node (1, [ Leaf 2; Leaf 3 ])
    let maxOf = findMaxOf t //will be 3
    maxOf
```

My problem is, I find this approach hard to follow. The mutual recursion (assuming that's the right term) is really clever to my simpleton brain, but I get lost while trying to understand how it works, even when using simple examples and writing down steps manually etc.

I am in need of using CPS with Rose trees, and I'll be doing the kind of traversals that require a CPS, because just like this example, computing results based on my my tree nodes require that children of the nodes are computed first. In any case, I do like CPS and I'd like to improve my understanding of it.

So my question is: Is there an alternative way of implementing CPS on rose trees which I may manage to better follow understand? Is there a way to refactor the above code which may make it easier to follow (eliminating the mutual recursion?)

If there is a name for the above approach, or some resources/books I can read to understand it better, hints are also most welcome.

Comment: I'd use a "zipper"....there this link http://tomasp.net/blog/tree-zipper-query.aspx/...though I havent read the article, there's coverage of list zippers in "learn you a haskell", best start learning list zipper.

Comment: actually I read the blog and I wouldnt use a zipper

Comment: The SubModelSeq sample in [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF) use rose trees from what I can see. I haven't got the faintest idea whether or not that can be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks @BentTranberg . I actually got a better understanding of the approach after working on it for some time but always good to know about more examples to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPS can definitely be confusing, but there are some things you can do to simplify this code:

- Remove the `Leaf` case from your type because it's redundant. A leaf is just a `Node` with an empty list of children.
- Separate general-purpose CPS logic from logic that's specific to rose trees.
- Use the continuation monad to simplify CPS code.

First, let's define the [continuation monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052256/how-does-continuation-monad-really-work):

```
type ContinuationMonad() =
    member __.Bind(m, f) = fun c -> m (fun a -> f a c)
    member __.Return(x) = fun k -> k x

let cont = ContinuationMonad()
```

Using this builder, we can define a general-purpose CPS `reduce` function that combines a list of "incomplete" computations into a single incomplete computation (where an incomplete computation is any function that takes a continuation of type `'t -> 'u` and uses it to produce a value of type `'u`).

```
let rec reduce fs =
    cont {
        match fs with
        | [] -> return []
        | head :: tail ->
            let! result = head
            let! results = reduce tail
            return result :: results
    }
```

I think this is certainly clearer, but it might seem like magic. The key to understanding `let! x = f` for this builder is that `x` is the value passed to `f`'s implied continuation. This allows us to get rid of lots of lambdas and nested parens.

Now we're ready to work with rose trees. Here's the simplified type definition:

```
type 'a Tree = Node of 'a * 'a Tree list

let leaf a = Node (a, [])
```

Finding the maximum value in a tree now looks like this:

```
let rec findMax (Node (i, chld)) =
    cont {
        let! maxVals = chld |> List.map findMax |> reduce
        return List.max (i :: maxVals)
    }
```

Note that there's no mutual recursion here. Both `reduce` and `findMax` are self-recursive, but `reduce` doesn't call `findMax` and doesn't know anything about rose trees.

You can test the refactored code like this:

```
let t = Node (1, [ leaf 2; leaf 3 ])
findMax t (printfn "%A")   // will be 3
```

For convenience, I created [a gist containing all the code](https://gist.github.com/brianberns/fff0a0ff252d39bcdc1cba048b7da027).

Comment: Thanks, that's really a cool way to reduce complexity, or arguably shift it to monadic thinking :) Anyway, I asked for alternative ways and you delivered.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from brianberns indeed provides an alternative way of achieving cps on a rose tree.

I'm also adding [this alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875835/fold-recursion-over-multiway-tree-in-f) from Tomas Petricek. It shows how we can eliminate the extra function call by changing the type of the tree from a single node to a list of nodes in the inner loop.

I should have used the term multiway tree (which I'll change in a minute) but at least this question now documents three different methods. Hopefully it'll help others.